# GRASS r.inund.fluv example of input files

Tags: grass-gis, references, add-ons

Does anyone have an example of input files for the GRASS r.inund.fluv add-on that can be shared?

I am asking because I am getting some errors when I am trying to run an the files that I created and I am looking for an example that I can follow.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider to ask the authors and invite them to enhance the manual page. They will know best how to deal with the preparation of the input data.